# Mostrar u ocultar icono si la palabra es igual en html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Mi duda es como hago en javascript para que si es el id pago es igual a pendiente solo muestre un icono mientras q si no lo es salgan los dos

```
            <td id="pago">Pendiente </td>

{% if  pago == %}
            <td class="iconosmostrar">
                <i id="btn" class="bi bi-credit-card"></i>
                <i id="btn" class="bi bi-file-earmark-arrow-down-fill"></i>
            </td>
{% else %}
            <td class="iconosmostrar">
                <i id="btn" class="bi bi-credit-card"></i>
                <i id="btn" class="bi bi-file-earmark-arrow-down-fill"></i>
            </td>
```

Comment: que boton hay que enseñar en caso de solo mostra uno?

Comment: Este 
<i id="btn" class="bi bi-credit-card"></i>

Comment: y las partes que tienen `{%` y `%}` son django (python)?

Comment: sip creo q si, por lo que busque al principio pense q era javascript

Comment: Javascript no es, asique olvidate... si no estas usando django no te va a servir de nada...

Comment: entonces como lo hago la verdad q ahora estoy perdido

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138257/discussion-between-adrigo-and-jose-antonio-rm).